# ItemRenderer and ActionScript Functions Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, itemrenderer

Okay, possibly my last flex problem :)

Got this ItemRenderer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" autoDrawBackground="false">


akwrenderer.mxml
    <s:Image source="{data.imgPath}"    verticalCenter="{data.y}" horizontalCenter="{data.x}"
             visible="{data.isShown}" scaleX="{negate}" scaleY="{negate}" click="selectAkw(event)" />
    <s:Ellipse  visible="{data.isShown}" height="{data.radiusDisp.height}" width="{data.radiusDisp.width}" 
                verticalCenter="{data.radiusDisp.y}" horizontalCenter="{data.radiusDisp.x}"
                alpha="0.5"   rotation="{data.radiusDisp.rotation}" bottom="0"
                transformY="{data.radiusDisp.transY}" >
        <s:fill>
            <s:RadialGradient>
                <s:entries>

<s:GradientEntry color="#006699" ratio="0.3" alpha="0.5"/>
                    <s:GradientEntry color="#006699" ratio="0.3" alpha="0.55"/>
                    <s:GradientEntry color="#006699" ratio="0.3" alpha="0.555"/>
                </s:entries>
            </s:RadialGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Ellipse> 
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

but I can't access **negate** and **selectAkw()** which are in script/control.as

anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this. The best way, in my opinion, is to pass the parameters to the item renderer using a class factory.

So add the properties to the itemRenderer

```
[Bindable]
private var negate:int = 0;
```

Now in the component calling it (do this in CreationComplete I guess)

```
var irFactory:ClassFactory = new ClassFactory(YourItemRenderer);
irFactory.properties = {negate:negate};
yourComponent.itemRenderer = irFactory;
```

You can also do that as an ItemRendererFunction

The cheater way to do it is `{FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.negate}` assuming negate is accessible in your main Application MXML file.

For your event, just dispatch a new event on click and capture it where the component is, then call your `SelectAKW()` function from there.

```
click="{dispatchEvent(new Event("selectThatAKW"))}"
```

then on the parent component in creationComplete:

```
 yourComponent.addEventListener("selectThatAKW",selectAkw)
```

Comment: akwrenderer.addEventListener("selectThatAKW",selectAkw); dosn't work :/

Comment: why not? is it not catching the event or is it not able to access selectAKW? It's kind of hard to debug without more source code.

Comment: OH! No, don't add the eventListener to the renderer, add it to the **COMPONENT**

Comment: but the component is called akwrenderer.mxml

Comment: No, in the code you posted it looks like that's the item renderer. You need to target the component that uses the item renderer. Is it a datagrid? A list? Whatever component uses the akwrenderer needs to have the event listener.